# Parsing String to Datestamp doesn't work. Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse String in format MMM-dd-yyyy to Timestamp. I'm doing this like below:

```
String dateto = "Dec-01-2013";
try{
    DateFormat datetoDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
    Date datetoD = (Date)datetoDF.parse(dateto);
    datetoTS = new Timestamp(datetoD.getTime());
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
    log.error("RegisteredUserDataProvider:getFilteredUsers:ParseException: " + e.getMessage());
    String stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
    log.error(stackTrace);
}
```

Why it works only with March (for example Mar-01-2013)?
When I give any other date with other month I get

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Dec-01-2013"
```

I've checked it for set of variables with every month:
"Dec-01-2013", "Nov-01-2013", "Oct-01-2013", "Sep-01-2013", "Aug-01-2013", "Jul-01-2013", "Jun-01-2013", "May-01-2013", "Apr-01-2013", "Feb-01-2013", "Jan-01-2013" and "Mar-04-2013". It works only for Mar. Any idea why?

Comment: worked for me. Your exact code. `sysout(datetoTS)` gave **2013-12-01 00:00:00.0**

Comment: Strange. So I have to dig deeper.

Comment: @R.J Its his Locale causing the issue. Your default Locale may be English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your Default `Locale` is different.

```
DateFormat datetoDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Your default Locale may not recognize the words "Jan", "Feb" etc.

Answer (score 1):

All about Local or you are passing date `Dec -01-2013` with space.
Provide proper date without space such as `Dec-01-2013`,and try to print `Locale.getDefault()` if your default is set something like Korea then definitely you will get this exception then try to use like

`DateFormat datetoDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
 String dateto = "Dec-01-2013";
 Date datetoD = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateto );
 datetoTS = new Timestamp(datetoD.getTime());
```